# xsp make error: target `Mono.WebServer.source' is not a directory

Tags: mono

I'm Microsoft .NET developer but newbie of Mono. On Cent0S 6.4, I have successfully install Mono. When I try to make & install xsp from http://download.mono-project.com/sources/xsp/xsp-2.10.tar.bz2, it gets the following error.

I google a lot but find nothing value. Any idea?

Thanks.

Leo

make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
/bin/sh /root/xsp-2.10/install-sh -d
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 Mono.WebServer.zip Mono.WebServer.tree Mono.WebServer        .source
/usr/bin/install: target`Mono.WebServer.source' is not a directory
make[3]: *** [install-data-local] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/xsp-2.10/docs/Mono.WebServer'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory`/root/xsp-2.10/docs/Mono.WebServer'
make[1]:**  [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/xsp-2.10/docs'
make: ** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: the latest one, mono-3.2.6.
I find the bug report https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=645212#c3. It seems related with pkg-config. But I don't how to do in light of Chad Wackerman. I just follow the first comment Mirko Sacripanti's advice and works well:
Step1: just only make
Step2: find the subdirs parameter in the generated makefile and remove the docs entry
Step3: make install

Hope this helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

xsp 2.x is not compatible with mono 3.x, upgrade to xsp 3.0.11

Comment: where is xsp 3.0.11? I can only find the latest xsp 2.10.2 from http://download.mono-project.com/sources/xsp/

Comment: there is no tarball, you have to use the git tag